# finding height on a heightmap stretched over a sphere C#

Tags: c#, math, angle, heightmap

I'm looking for a bit of math help. I have a game were a 2D heightmap is generated and then stretched over a sphere using a length/direction formula. Now I need to know how to calculate the height between 2 points on my heightmap.

What I know:

- The array that holds the heightmap
- The angle in radians to my object
- how many points there are on the heightmap

My problem look somewhat like so:

[image](http://memberfiles.freewebs.com/67/76/61827667/photos/undefined/gah.png)

[more images](http://spine-games.webs.com/apps/photos/album?albumid=14391435)

The red and blue lines are the 2 heightmap points, and the light blue is where I'd like to calculate the height at.

Here's my current code to do it, but it doesn't work to well.

```
public double getheight(double angle)
{
    //find out angle between 2 heightmap point
    double offset = MathHelper.TwoPi / (heightmap.Length - 1);
    //total brainfart attempt
    double lowerAngle = offset * angle;
    double upperAngle = offset * angle + offset;
    //find heights
    double height1 = heightmap[(int)lowerAngle];
    double height2 = heightmap[(int)upperAngle];
    //find offset angle
    double u = angle - lowerAngle / (upperAngle - lowerAngle);
    //return the height
    return height1 + (height1 - height2) * u;
}
```

from my vegetation code, this seems to work okay, but is to rough to use for units and such, as they jump up/down as they move, due to it using only 1 heightmap point.

```
double[] hMap = planet.getHeightMap();
double i = hMap.Length / (Math.PI * 2);
this.height = hMap[(int)(angle * i)];
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: example at end based on additional question info**

Sounds to me like a linear interpolation - if you look at it from a 2d point of view, you've got two points:

```
(x1, y1) = point one on heightmap
(x2, y2) = point two on heightmap
```

and one point somewhere between `(x1,x2)` at an unknown height:

```
pu = (xu, yu)
```

A generic formula for LERP is:

```
pu = p0 + (p1 - p0) * u
```

where:

- `p0` = first value
- `p1` = second value
- `u` = % where your unknown point lies between `(p0,p1)`

Here, we'll say `p0` == `y2` and `p1` == `y1`. Now we need to determine "how far" the unknown point is between `x1` and `x2` - if you know the angles to the two heightmap points, this is easy:

```
u = ang(xu) - ang(x1) / (ang(x2) - ang(x1))
```

Alternatively, you could project your angle out to `Max(y1,y2)` and get the "unknown x pos" that way, then calculate the above.

So, let's try a contrived example:

```
p1 = point one in map = (1,2) therefore ang(p1) ~ 57 degrees
p2 = point two in map = (2,4) therefore ang(p2) ~ 114 degrees
```

note that here, the "x axis" is along the surface of the sphere, and the "y-axis" is the distance away from the center.

```
pu = object location = py @angle 100 degrees ~ 1.74 radians

px = (1.74 rad - 1 rad ) / (2 rad - 1 rad) = 0.74 / 1.0 = 0.74 => 74%

py = y0 + (y1 - y0) * u
   = 2 + (4 - 2) * 0.74
   = 2.96
```

Hopefully I didn't drop or misplace a sign there somewhere... :)

Ok, your example code - I've tweaked it a bit, here's what I've come up with:

First, let's define some helpers of my own:

```
public static class MathHelper
{
    public const double TwoPi = Math.PI * 2.0;
    public static double DegToRad(double deg)
    {
        return (TwoPi / 360.0) * deg;
    }
    public static double RadToDeg(double rad)
    {
        return (360.0 / TwoPi) * rad;
    }

    // given an upper/lower bounds, "clamp" the value into that
    // range, wrapping over to lower if higher than upper, and
    // vice versa    
    public static int WrapClamp(int value, int lower, int upper)
    {
        return value > upper ? value - upper - 1
            : value < lower ? upper - value - 1
            : value;
    }
}
```

Our Test setup:

```
void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();

    // "sea level"
    var baseDiameter = 10;

    // very chaotic heightmap
    heightmap = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 360)
        .Select(_ => random.NextDouble() * baseDiameter)
        .ToArray();

    // let's walk by half degrees, since that's roughly how many points we have
    for(double i=0;i<360;i+=0.5)
    {
        var angleInDegrees = i;
        var angleInRads = MathHelper.DegToRad(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Height at angle {0}°({1} rad):{2} (using getheight:{3})",
            angleInDegrees,
            angleInRads,
            heightmap[(int)angleInDegrees],
            getheight(angleInRads));
    }
}

double[] heightmap;
```

And our "getheight" method:

```
// assume: input angle is in radians
public double getheight(double angle)
{
    //find out angle between 2 heightmap point
    double dTheta = MathHelper.TwoPi / (heightmap.Length);

    // our "offset" will be how many dThetas we are
    double offset = angle / dTheta;

    // Figure out two reference points in heightmap
    // THESE MAY BE THE SAME POINT, if angle ends up
    // landing on a heightmap index!
    int lowerAngle = (int)offset;
    int upperAngle = (int)Math.Round(
        offset, 
        0, 
        MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    // find closest heightmap points to angle, wrapping
    // around if we go under 0 or over max
    int closestPointIndex = MathHelper.WrapClamp(
        lowerAngle, 
        0, 
        heightmap.Length-1);
    int nextPointIndex = MathHelper.WrapClamp(
        upperAngle, 
        0, 
        heightmap.Length-1);

    //find heights
    double height1 = heightmap[closestPointIndex];
    double height2 = heightmap[nextPointIndex];

    // percent is (distance from angle to closest angle) / (angle "step" per heightmap point)
    double percent = (angle - (closestPointIndex * dTheta)) / dTheta;

    // find lerp height = firstvalue + (diff between values) * percent
    double lerp = Math.Abs(height1 + (height2 - height1) * percent);

    // Show what we're doing
    Console.WriteLine("Delta ang:{0:f3}, Offset={1:f3} => compare indices:[{2}, {3}]", 
        dTheta, 
        offset, 
        closestPointIndex, 
        nextPointIndex);
    Console.WriteLine("Lerping {0:p} between heights {1:f4} and {2:f4} - lerped height:{3:f4}", 
        percent,
        height1, 
        height2,
        lerp);

    return lerp;
}
```